# How can I substitute variables for querying DynamoDB attributes?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to generalize a DynamoDB query using a Python Lambda function. There are numerous examples of ProjectionExpression being set to include the actual values of the attributes in the database, e. g. ProjectionExpression='cats, dogs'. I can't find any examples of the attributes being set in a variable such as below. I want to pass in the values of the attributes to retrieve with the query string event.

```
attr1 = 'cats'
attr2 = 'dogs'
response = table.query(
    IndexName='pets-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key(queryparamKey).eq(queryparamKeyID),
    # Get two attr
    # Does not work
    #ProjectionExpression="attr1, attr2"
    # Neither does this
    #ExpressionAttributeNames='{"#attr1":attr1,"#attr2":attr2}'
)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037452/how-can-i-dynamically-substitute-where-condition-parameters-in-dynamodb) is the idea but is for javascript and uses ExpressionAttributeNames.

This can't be all that esoteric, but I am only now encountering Python and I have not found any postings. Please advise.

Comment: It seems a Python problem, rather than Lambda one.

Comment: @BAD_SEED Thanks for your classification. It IS a Python syntax problem in forming a DynamoDB query in a Lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some additional floundering with Python syntax I found this is what works:

```
ProjectionExpression=attr1+","+attr2
```

The ProjectionExpression='attr, attr2' was not being evaluated correctly so I got a KeyError when I tried to build a response like:

```
'body': response['Items'][0][attr1]+"|"+response['Items'][0][attr2]
```

Hope this saves some other Python newbies some floundering.

Answer (score 1):

Say if you want to get only `attr1` and `attr2` from your table using `pets-index` where the `pet_type` partition key is `cats`, this should work:

```py
response = table.query(
    IndexName='pets-index',
    KeyConditionExpression='pet_type = :value',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':value': {'S': 'cats'}
    },
    ProjectionExpression='attr1,attr2'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This did not work for me because my schema is a little different from what you assumed.

Comment: Yes, clearly. This is an example that I hoped would get you on the right track. If you would provide details about your schema in the question, I could update my answer so it fits your use case.